# How to change the colors of Legends in AM Bar Charts?

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

What I have now is
[image: Current]

But I want to change the colors of Legends, and achieve like below as it should match the colors of the bars.
[image: Desired One]

Despite trying *chart.legend.backround.fill* and *chart.legend.data* with fill property, I am unable to change the colors

Comment: Can you please share vour chart config, or create a code pen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Samuel
I have solved my problem!
[image: Desired Output]

`Chart.legend.data = [{
            "name": "Normal",
            "fill": "#28a745"
        }, {
            "name": "Underweight",
            "fill": "#ffc107"
        }];`

Was missing!

The Code Pen can be found [Here](https://codepen.io/SDawood/pen/oOvdrv)